# Given $\triangle BPD$ with $O$ the midpoint of $\overline{BD}$, project $P$ to $P'$ and show that $|OB||OP'|$ is independent of $|BD|$.

Tags: geometry

[This recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3373997/409) (put on-hold for lack of context) presented the following:

> **Original Question.** Let $ABCD$ be a square and let $P$ be a point inside it such that $|PD|=29$ and $|PB|=23$. Find the area of $\triangle APC$.

As [@JeanMarie's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3374030/409) indicates, the answer is (perhaps surprisingly) independent of the size of the square. In general, the prescribed area can be given as

> $$|\triangle APC| = \frac14\,\left|\,|PB|^2-|PD|^2\,\right| \tag{1}$$

My approach (which I couldn't post because the question was closed) was as follows: Project $P$ to $P'$ on $\overline{BD}$; then $\triangle APC$ and $\triangle AP'C$ (which share base $\overline{AC}$ and have congruent corresponding heights) have equal areas, so we just need to find the latter.

[image]

Of course, that area is (writing $O$ for the center of the square):
$$|\triangle AP'C| = \tfrac12 |AC||OP'| = |OA||OP'|=|OB||OP'| \tag{2}$$
With the far-right expression, we find that we can ditch the square context and the goal of computing an area, reformulating the question something like this:

> **Reformulated Question.** For $\triangle BPD$ with $O$ the midpoint of $\overline{BD}$, let $P'$ be the projection of $P$ onto $\overline{BD}$. Show that $|OB||OP'|$ is independent of $|BD|$ (or, if you prefer, $\angle P$).
>
> Specifically, taking the target to be a *signed* product (negative, if $\overrightarrow{OB}$ and $\overrightarrow{OP'}$ are oppositely-directed; positive otherwise) show that the value is given by
> $$|OB||OP'| = \frac14\left(\;|PD|^2 - |PB|^2\;\right) \tag{3}$$

[image]

My answer to the Reformulated Question appears below. Other approaches are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A recall : The product of "algebraic lengthes" of a vector $\vec{u}$ with the projection of another vector $\vec{v}$ on the axis defined by vector $\vec{u}$ is their **dot product** $\vec{u}.\vec{v}$.

Therefore, it suffices to prove, with vector notations, that

> $$\vec{OP}.\vec{OB}=\tfrac14\left(\vec{PD}^2-\vec{PB}^2\right)\tag{1}$$

In fact, (1) boils down to the well-known relationship (valid in any inner product space) :

$$\vec{u}.\vec{v} = \dfrac14\left(\|\vec{u}+\vec{v}\|^2 - \|\vec{u}-\vec{v}\|^2\right),$$

with $\vec{u}:=\vec{OP}$ and $\vec{v}:=\vec{OB}$.

(Indeed $\vec{OP}+\vec{OB}=\vec{DP}$ and $\vec{OP}-\vec{OB}=\vec{BP}$.)

Answer (score 2):

Apply the Pythagorean theorem to the right triangles BPP' and DPP' that share the height PP’,

$$PB^2 - (OB+OP')^2 = PD^2 - (OB-OP')^2 $$

which yields the result,

$$OB\cdot OP' = \frac14\left(PB^2 - PD^2\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Define $b := \tfrac12|PB|$ and $d :=\tfrac12|PD|$, and let $M$ be the midpoint of $\overline{PB}$. Note that $\overline{OM}$ is a midpoint segment of $\triangle BPD$, so it has length $d$.

Now, since $\angle PP'B$ is a right angle, [Thales' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27s_theorem) tells us that $P'$ lies on the circle with diameter $\overline{PB}$ (with center $M$).

[image]

Finally, we simply observe that the *signed* product $|OB||OP'|$ gives the [power of point $O$ with respect to $\bigcirc PP'B$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point), so that

> $$|OB||OP'| = |MO|^2 - (\text{radius})^2 = d^2 - b^2 = \frac14\left(\,|PD|^2-|PB|^2\,\right) \tag{$\star$}$$

as desired. $\square$

Comment: Signed product $|OB||OP'|$ is plainly dot product $\vec{OB}.\vec{OP}$ (reference to projection $P'$ isn't needed in this way)

Answer (score 1):

Circumscribe a circle around triangle $BP'P$, which will have a centre $S$ in the middle of $PB$. Let $r=|PB|/2$ be the radius of that circle and let $OS$ intersect the circle in points $X$ and $Y$:

[image: Circle]

Note that $|OS|=|PD|/2$ as a midsegment. If we for a moment assume that $|PB|\ge|PD|$, then $O$ is inside the circle.

Now, it is well known that:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}|OP'|\cdot|OB|&=&|OX|\cdot |OY|\\&=&(r-|OS|)(r+|OS|)\\&=&r^2-|OS|^2\\&=&(|PB|/2)^2-(|PD|/2)^2\\&=&\frac{1}{4}(|PB|^2-|PD|^2)\end{array}$$

The claim then follows because the product "as vectors", for $O$ within the circle, is taken with the negative sign.

The consideration is very similar in the case $|PB|\le|PD|$, except that, in that case, $O$ is outside the circle.

Comment: Yep. See [my simultaneously-posted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3375838/409). :)  (I didn't expect anyone to respond until after I'd posted the answer I promised.)

Comment: BTW: If no one comes up with a clever approach that we both missed, I'll accept your answer over mine.

Comment: @Blue No worries, there is a third candidate now which looks like a winner. Thanks anyways.